# Connecting Pyspark with Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I'm having problem understanding how to connect Kafka and PySpark.

I have kafka installation on Windows 10 with topic nicely streaming data.
I've installed pyspark which runs properly-I'm able to create test DataFrame without problem.

But when I try to connect to Kafka stream it gives me error:

> AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy
> the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming-
> Kafka Integration Guide".

Spark documentation is not really helpful - it says:
...
*groupId = org.apache.spark
artifactId = spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12
version = 3.2.0*
...

*For Python applications, you need to add this above library and its dependencies when deploying your application. See the Deploying subsection below.*

And then when you go to Deploying section it says:

*As with any Spark applications, spark-submit is used to launch your application. spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12 and its dependencies can be directly added to spark-submit using --packages, such as,
./bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.0 ...*

I'm developing app, I don't want to deploy it.
Where and how to add these dependencies if I'm developing pyspark app?

Tried several tutorials ended up being more confused.

Saw answer saying that

> "You need to add kafka-clients JAR to your --packages".[so-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62876418/2119941)

Few more steps could be useful because for someone who is new this is unclear.

**versions**:

- kafka 2.13-2.8.1
- spark 3.1.2
- java 11.0.12

All environmental variables and paths are correctly set.

**EDIT**

I've load :

```
   os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2,org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.8.1'
```

as suggested but still getting same error.
I've triple checked kafka, scala and spark versions and tried various combinations but not it didn't work, I'm still getting same error:

> AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy
> the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming-Kafka Integration Guide".

**EDIT 2**

I installed latest Spark 3.2.0 and Hadoop 3.3.1 and kafka version kafka_2.12-2.8.1. Changed all environmental variables, tested Spark and Kafka - working properly.

My environment variable looks like this now:

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.0,org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.8.1'
```

Still no luck, I get same error :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Spark documentation is not really helpful - it says ...  artifactId = spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12 version = 3.2.0 ...

Yes, that is correct... but you're looking at documentation for the **latest** version of Spark

Instead, you've mentioned

> versions:
>
> - spark 3.1.2

Have you tried looking at the [version specific docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)?

In other words, you want the matching `spark-sql-kafka` version of 3.1.2.

`bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2`

Or in Python,

```
scala_version = '2.12'
spark_version = '3.1.2'
# TODO: Ensure match above values match the correct versions
packages = [
    f'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_{scala_version}:{spark_version}',
    'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.2.1'
]
spark = SparkSession.builder\
   .master("local")\
   .appName("kafka-example")\
   .config("spark.jars.packages", ",".join(packages))\
   .getOrCreate()
```

Or with an env-var

```
import os

spark_version = '3.1.2'
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:{}'.format(spark_version)

# init spark here
```

> need to add this above library and its dependencies

As you found in my previous answer, also append the `kafka-clients` package using comma-separated list.

`--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2,org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.8.1`

---

> I'm developing app, I don't want to deploy it.

"Deploy" is Spark terminology. Running locally is still a "*deployment*"

Comment: Thank you so much for this! One thing is still not clear to me - how do I 'append the kafka-clients package' ? Where is that package?

Comment: Also https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html says: "Do not manually add dependencies on org.apache.kafka artifacts (e.g. kafka-clients). The spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 artifact has the appropriate transitive dependencies already, and different versions may be incompatible in hard to diagnose ways."

Comment: Last I checked, PySpark doesn't pull the transitive dependencies (thus, the reported error in the answer you linked), only when using a tool like SBT / Maven / Gradle, it does. As for "where" - Maven Central. You "append" a string to the packages argument, as shown

Comment: I've tried as you suggested - see edit on my question. It's still not working :(

Comment: You put the `{}` formatter at the wrong spot. It only goes to the Spark dependencies, not at the very end

Comment: I've edited answer - not working again. Problem is that my Kafka is for Scala version 2.13 and Spark requires 2.12. I'll reinstall kafka and try again...

Comment: I'm using latest Spark 3.2.0 and kafka_2.12-2.8.1 but still no luck.

Comment: The scala api version for the Kafka broker shouldn't matter. As long as your Spark version and **Spark's** scala version are the same as the packages argument, then it'll work. Where are you putting `os.environ` call in relation to the Spark code? Are you importing `findspark`, perhaps?

Comment: @user12 It's correct, and been answered [other times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58723314/pyspark-failed-to-find-data-source-kafka/58723724#58723724) too