# How to set up Kafka as a dependency when using Delta Lake in PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-kafka, databricks, delta-lake

This is the code to set up Delta Lake as part of a regular Python script, according to [their documentation](https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#python):

```py
import pyspark
from delta import *

builder = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")

spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()
```

[The official docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#deploying) for Kafka integration in Spark show how to set up Kafka when using a `spark-submit` command (through the `--packages` parameter), but not in Python.

[Digging around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70382002/344162), turns out that you can also include this parameter when building the Spark session:

```py
import pyspark
from delta import *

packages = [
    "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.1",
]

builder = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", ",".join(packages))
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")

spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()
```

However, when I try to stream to Kafka using the spark session created above I still get the following error:

`Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".`

I'm using Delta 2.1.0 and PySpark 3.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Delta overwrites any packages provided in `spark.jars.packages` if you're using `configure_spark_with_delta_pip` ([source](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/794#issuecomment-931703978)). The proper way is to make use of the `extra_packages` parameter when setting up your Spark Session:

```py
import pyspark
from delta import *

packages = [
    "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.1",
]

builder = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")

spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder, extra_packages=packages).getOrCreate()
```

Comment: remove `builder` variable, you don't need it

Comment: @AlexOtt, how come? it is a required variable for `configure_spark_with_delta_pip`

Comment: ah, sorry - misread the code